# How to add authentication token dynamically in readiness probe

Tags: azure, authentication, kubernetes, deployment, azure-aks

This question is extension for https://stackoverflow.com/a/60142788/22370266
In this solution we have applied hard-coded bearer token, how do I make it dynamic.

I have added the token like this :

```
readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /path
          port: 8080
          scheme: HTTP
          httpHeaders:
            - name: Authorization
              value: >-
                    Bearer
                    Hardcoded-token
```

But I don't know how do I make it dynamic.

I donot know if this is possible or not. I have only seen that environment varible is added and that variable is refered in curl command.

Comment: To add an authentication token dynamically in a readiness probe, you can use a Kubernetes environment variable that contains the authentication token then update your readiness probe to use the environment variable for the authentication token.

Answer (score 0):

To add an authentication token dynamically in a readiness probe, you can use a Kubernetes environment variable.
First, create an environment variable that contains the authentication token. You can do this by adding the following to your deployment manifest:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ubuntu
        image: ubuntu:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: AUTH_TOKEN
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: my-secret
              key: auth-token
```

Then, update your readiness probe to use the environment variable for the authentication token. You can do this by replacing the Hardcoded-token value in the following code with the environment variable name:

```
readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /path
          port: 8080
          scheme: HTTP
          httpHeaders:
            - name: Authorization
              value: >-
                    Bearer ${AUTH_TOKEN}
```

Once you have updated your deployment manifest, you can deploy the changes. Kubernetes will then replace the `$(AUTH_TOKEN)` placeholder with the value of the `AUTH_TOKEN` environment variable. You can set the value of the `AUTH_TOKEN` environment variable dynamically using a number of different methods. For example, you could use a Kubernetes secret as below-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: my-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  auth-token: dXNlci1hY2Nlc3MtdG9rZW4
```

[image]
[image]